# Launching redis-server with the Latest Version

Tags: redis, redis-py, redis-cli

I've downloaded Redis 3.2.5 which has the functionality for `PFADD` and I intend on using it.
Initially, I used to simply type redis-server in my root directory and it used to launch in the version 2.6.9.

After a little searching, I found out that going to `cd redis.3.2.5/` and then running the same command it would work, and it did start at 3.2.5 that time, but now again when I ty it it's back at 2.6.9.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old binaries exist in your $PATH, while your new ones don't.

You need to replace your old Redis binaries with the new ones.

You can find the location of the old redis-server binary by typing `which redis-server`.